# Why the container div height was not updated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding elements into a container div whose height is 'auto' initially. I expect its height will be updated as the children elements appended. But, actually not. Could someone help me? I just want the container div height gets updated according to the children's height.

I used chrome debuging tool, the height of container div is less than height of children divs. **Children divs are float:left**.

Comment: Does it not resize when you insert element? Or is it just the height-property, that does not update?

Comment: We can't help unless you show some structure. What kind of children are you adding? Are they floated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're adding floated children to a div you need to have `overflow:auto;` on the parent.

You can also use another element to clear the float `clear:both` will do this.

This is because floated elements are taken out of the document flow.

Here's an example that shows you a few techniques you can use : http://jsfiddle.net/Tn5c3/

**The CSS**

```
#a, #b {
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10xp
}

#a {
    background: #aa0000;
}
#b {
    background: #00aa00;
    overflow: auto;
}
p {
    background: #0000aa;
    padding: 5px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**The JS**

```
$('#bb').click(function() {
    addChild($('#b')); 
});

$('#ba').click(function() {
    addChild($('#a')); 
});


function addChild(parent) {
    var child = $('<p>floated para</p>').css({
        'float': 'left'
    });
    parent.append(child);
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<button id='ba'>Add to A</button>
<button id='bb'>Add to B</button>


<div id='a'></div>
<div class='clear'></div>
<div id='b'></div>
```

Comment: Note that the DIV with ID 'a' is not meant to work. You can easily make it work by moving the `clear` div inside it and changign the JS call `append` to a `prepend` (The clear div needs to come last)

Comment: I want to know is there side effect if I have to set the parent div overflow:auto?

Comment: @todd there aren't any. None that I know of anyway.